# Random Walks proof SOS

Tags: functions, random

Given this equation:

$f_{2k}2^{2k}u_{2n-2k}2^{2n-2k}$=$f_{2k}u_{2n-2k}2^{2n}$

then it asks to "sum over k" to obtain this equation:

$u_{2n}2^{2n}$=$f_0u_{2n}2^{2n}+f_2u_{2n-2} 2^{2n}$+....+$f_{2n}u_02^{2n}$

then dividing both sides of the equation by $2^{2n}$ completes the proof I need.

My question is, what does it mean by "sum over k"

Does it want me to sum from 0 to $\infty$ for k? And which k, all of them? And how? Do I start by plugging in o to all k's and see what happens? continue then add them all up? Seems strange to me! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what does it mean by "sum over k"

Obviously, summing from $k=0$ to $k=n$.

Comment: You really should indicate your source, you know?

Comment: Sorry, I see it now too!Do Forgive! Nice Philippe quote

Comment: Not what I call indicating a source. Please do it.